# aria2c timeout error on large file, but downloads most of it

Tags: aria2

I posted this on `superuser` yesterday, but maybe it's better here. I apologize if I am incorrect.

I am trying to trouble shoot the below `aria2c` command run using `ubuntu 14.04`. Basically the download starts and gets to about 30 minutes left, then errors with a timeout error. The file being downloaded is 25GB and there is often multiple files that are downloaded using a loop. Any suggestions to make this more efficient and stable? Currently, the each file takes about 4 hours to download, which is ok as long as there are no errors. I do get an `aria2c` file with the partial dowloaded file as well.  Thank you :).

```
aria2c -x 4 -l log.txt -c -d /home/cmccabe/Desktop/download --http-user "xxxxx"  --http-passwd xxxx xxx://www.example.com/x/x/xxx/"file"
```

I apologize for the tag as I am not able to create a new one, that was the closest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a loop to rerun aria2c until all files are download (see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jonbakerfish/0f7877c050b648169e0958ea2e2c6aca)).

Basically, you can put all the links in a file (e.g. `list.txt`):

```
http://foo/file1
http://foo/file2
...
```

Then run `loop_aria2.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
aria2c -j5 -i list.txt -c --save-session out.txt
has_error=`wc -l < out.txt`

while [ $has_error -gt 0 ]
do
  echo "still has $has_error errors, rerun aria2 to download ..."
  aria2c -j5 -i list.txt -c --save-session out.txt
  has_error=`wc -l < out.txt`
  sleep 10
done
```

`aria2c -j5 -i list.txt -c --save-session out.txt` will downloads 5 files in parallel (`-j5`) and writes the failed files into `out.txt`. If the `out.txt` is not empty (`$has_error -gt 0`), then rerun the same command to continue downloading. The `-c` option of aria2c will skip completed files.

PS: another simpler solution (without checking error), which just run the aria2 1000 times if you don't mind :)

```
seq 1000 | parallel -j1 aria2c -i list.txt -c
```